# Image Magick: how to convert png file into raw NV21 and NV12

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, imagick, nv12-nv21

Is it possible to convert png image using Image Magick into raw NV21 or NV12 formart ?

I do the following:

```
convert test_color.png -size 1024x768 -depth 8 -colorspace Rec601YCbCr yuv:image.bin
```

The converted image is YV12 according to the rawpixels.net

I want to convert the picture into NV21 for the reference to test my converters.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `-size 1024x768` in that command, it is unnecessary as the output image will be the size of the input image (`test_color.png`) which is encoded in that file.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the NV21 format you want, i.e. describe it accurately and completely or give a link to a very clear description of what you need.

Comment: What is `rawpixels.net` which you refer to please?

Comment: I am using `ffmpeg` to do that. What are the benefits of `ImageMagick`?

Comment: @Rotem If you have a good `ffmpeg` solution please add it as an answer so folks are aware of it and can vote for it. We are all here to share and learn.

Comment: Example for converting `png` to `nv12` Rec. 601: `ffmpeg -y -colorspace bt470bg -i 1.png -pix_fmt nv12 1.yuv`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can't give an answer using `ffmpeg`, because the question is about  `ImageMagick`.

Comment: I don't see it that strictly! If an answer is relevant, useful and works I think it is fine to post it. It could be that OP and/or others were unaware that a different tool could do the job. If OP or others doesn't want to, or can't, use a different tool, they can just ignore it. No harm done. Obviously don't post answers to every single question on Stack Overflow in assembly language, or BASIC.... but you know what I mean.